# Connect API to Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I have searched for tons of threads here in Stack Overflow but I can't seem to find the fitting or direct answers.

So we would like to fetch products from API of external (outside Shopify) source then upload them to Shopify. Is there a way to do this without creating an app? This external source API provides already data in Shopify format.

Thanks!

Comment: Other options to upload are manually or purchasing a third party product, an app, build using the Shopify framework and sdk,  https://shopify.dev/api/storefront .  To automate the process of fetching the product (from an external API) and loading to Shopify is to have a middle application or app using the tools provided by Shopify.

Comment: You don't need "an app" but you definetly need an access token. So you have to create a custom (offline) app that gives you the token. With the token you can do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

No you have to create APP for it.

As per latest updates from Shopify, you need to create "Custom App" atleast to get the Access Tokens and API keys, because Shopify has depreciated "Private apps" They work like Private apps, as those apps are specific to only one store, but these apps can give you all the needed permission to Create and Fetch Products.

You can create new apps from admin panel here: [YourStoreDomain]/admin/settings/apps/development

Documentations realated to it is: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/custom-apps

> From Shopify: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps
> Note Private apps are deprecated and can't be created as of January
> 2022. Ask your app developer to create a custom app. Like private apps, custom apps are built exclusively for your shop, but they don't
> require open API access to your store or access to your Shopify admin.

Answer (score 0):

In the Shopify store you wish to add these products to, you can create an access token with permission to create products. Using that token, you are free to make API calls to the Shopify store, with the data representing products, to create products in the Shopify store. Very simple pattern. Takes about 30 seconds of your time to create the access token in the Shopify store admin.